# Подсчет числа упоминаний организаций в тексте

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, natasha

Возник вопрос по функционалу библиотеки `Natasha`.
Допустим, требуется извлечь именованные сущности (`named entities`) из текста, а затем подсчитать частоту упоминания каждой в этом тексте. Путем сегментирования текста и `NER` можно увидеть подобные сущности в тексте:

```py
from natasha import (
    Segmenter,
    NewsNERTagger,
    NewsEmbedding,
    Doc,
    ORG
)

segmenter = Segmenter()
emb = NewsEmbedding()
ner_tagger = NewsNERTagger(emb)

text = "Газпром планирует приобрести компанию Апекс Банк за 1 миллиард рублей. Газпром обозначил, что переговоры уже начаты."

doc = Doc(text)

doc.segment(segmenter)

doc.tag_ner(ner_tagger)

doc.ner.print()
```

Как результат будет такая визуализация:

```
Газпром планирует приобрести компанию Апекс Банк за 1 миллиард рублей.
ORG────                               ORG───────                      
Газпром обозначил, что переговоры уже начаты.
ORG────
```

Однако, мне требуется получить лист с частотой упоминаемости, вроде такого:

```
2 Газпром
1 Апекс Банк
```

В документации `natasha` есть предзаготовленные экстракторы дат, персон и денежных единиц, но по организациям нет; указано обращаться к библиотеке `yargy` и писать свой экстрактор. Но `yargy` ищет только предзаданные конструкции (на сколько понимаю), я же не знаю, какие организации могут быть упомянуты в тексте (в примере дал короткий, но на практике они больше). Каков может алгоритм решения проблемы, что я упускаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter([org.text for org in doc.spans if org.type =='ORG'])
print(counter.most_common())
```

Суть в том, что размеченный текст находится в `doc.spans`, можно перебрать его элементы и взять из них нужные. Ну и посчитать их.